# Organising a result query

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am trying to write a program (either [python](/questions/tagged/python) or [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)) to extract saved passwords from the chromium web browser.

What I've found so far, the following command extracts the web site address, username and password:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.config/chromium/Default/"Login Data" "select * from logins" | cut -d "|" -f 1,4,6
```

The data however is displayed on the screen and not neatly organised. What I am trying to do is store the data neatly.

1. The output is at the moment delimited by a | , instead I'd like this delimited by a tab (\t)
2. I'd like to prefix a header on top
3. The first column has http:// or https:// preceding the website address, I'd like that stripped.
4. If possible I'd like to be able to contain all that in a single script. If bash is ill suited for this, I am willing to try different programming language as required.
5. Any other suggestions are most welcome because I'm doing this as a hobby. The more I get to learn the better.

I am looking for suggestions on what I can do. Upon my last thread I was suggested to post on codereview stack exchange site instead for suggestion. If this is also better suited there forgive my noobness, and if possible tell me how I could move this.

Comment: Could you post a sample output? What you got and how you expect it.

Comment: Erm the sample output will have the website I visit + myusername and password so I hope you understand why I can't post that. 

This is however how it looks: 1 line out of 25 that was printed:

https://hackforums.net/member.php|<username>|<password>

Comment: Oh and I am obviously using Linux [bash shell should be a dead giveaway], specifically Lubunu operating system [though fairly certain that should not change the code required]

Comment: So you've posted what you got. How do you expect to store the data?

Comment: I want this to be stored in a text file (this much I can do), with a header (which I am unsure how to do) and tab seperated. 

the website name is also preceded by http:// or https:// depending on the nature of the website, I'd like that stripped as well if possible. 

Other, honestly I am open to suggestion. I am just doing this as something I like to do. So there really is not hard and fast formatting required. As long as it looks neat and presentable I'm relatively happy. 

Does any of that makes sense? Sorry if it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you saved the results of your query in a file called `/path/to/file`:

```
$ cat script
#!/bin/bash
sed -i '1iURL|Username|Password' /path/to/file
sed -i 's|http.*//||g' /path/to/file
awk -F"|" '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' /path/to/file | column -t > /path/to/output
```

This should do it.

**Line1**: `sed -i '1iURL|Username|Password' /path/to/file`: Adds header to your file

**Line2**: `sed -i 's|http.*//||g' /path/to/file`: Strips the http*// from your file

**Line3**: `awk -F"|" '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' /path/to/file | column -t > /path/to/output`: formats the output to a new file: `/path/to/output`

Comment: Sure will do. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.